# What is the difference between include_directories and target_include_directories in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a directory structure for my C++ code which goes like this :

```
|
|->include
|->src
```

I am writing a CMakeLists.txt  file for my code. I want to understand the difference between `include_directories` and `target_include_directories` in `CMake`.

What is the difference between their usage and in order to add my include file path which one should I be using?

Comment: There is no clarity in the documentation. I read it and surmised what Angew has written in his answer, but there are no descriptions, no examples and for a system that is meant for project building, there are no project based examples in CMake documentation. Had there been a good and exhaustive documentation of CMake, I would not have been burdening the community with these questions.

Comment: Concepts of cmake is poorly documented. Particularly target and “untargeted”.

Comment: Agree that CMake documentation is bad, how much effort do they save to not provide examples? When I was new to CMake I was often confused with old/new syntaxes.

Comment: 30 years of coding experience has taught me that undocumented software is as good as non-existent software and poorly documented software is worse than code that doesn't even compile.  As such I think this question should be treated like a bug report.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

`include_directories(x/y)` affects directory scope. All targets in this CMakeList, as well as those in all subdirectories added after the point of its call, will have the path `x/y` added to their include path.

`target_include_directories(t x/y)` has target scope—it adds `x/y` to the include path for target `t`.

You want the former one if all of your targets use the include directories in question. You want the latter one if the path is specific to a target, or if you want finer control of the path's visibility. The latter comes from the fact that `target_include_directories()` supports the `PRIVATE`, `PUBLIC`, and `INTERFACE` qualifiers.

Comment: I think the latter one should generally be preferred (as long as one is using cmake 3). It has the added benefit of putting ``x/y`` in the include path of any dependent targets that use ``t`` in their ``target_link_libraries`` commands. Of course there is a place for the former, but I believe the latter is generally better.

Comment: The original answer stated that only targets and subdirs added after `include_directories` will be affected. I'm editing the answer: the documentation clearly states that *all* targets in the current CMakeLists are affected. The documentation does not mention but only subdirs after the call are affected (as was correctly stated in the original answer)

Comment: @Phil, `target_include_directories` has been introduced in CMake 2.8.11 (May 2013)

Comment: @tamas.kenez Thanks for bringing this to my attention, fixed. I was quite convinced it was a "from now on" thing.

Comment: I should Greasemonkey your answer onto the official documentation for `include_directories`, concise and clear, thank you!  So then `target_include_directories` is a carpenter's hammer and `include_directories` is a sledge hammer.

Comment: so can we say that  include_directories will need more compile time than target_include_directories since every library will need to search the directories in include_directories ?

Comment: 100x clearer than the docs. as of July 2022 they never mention "include path" anywhere and all I needed was these two little words put next to each other

Comment: Anyone know how to print out the directories stored by target_include_directories? I tried the code provided here, and the result is always empty: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902149/listing-include-directories-in-cmake

Comment: @Oscar You need to retrieve the property `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` of the *target.* The question you're linking to retrieves the property of the *directory.*

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO Thanks! I did realize that at some point and got it working.

Answer (score 70):

Besides what [Angew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31969632/2436175) correctly says, another very important difference between `include_directories` and `target_include_directories` is that, when used with `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE`, the latter populates the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of the target. This property is useful when another target uses `target_link_libraries` to link to the original target, as the linking target will have automatically those include directories added. See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40242257/2436175).

This important feature is pretty well hidden in the documentation: [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) mention populating `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, whose [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) says:

> When target dependencies are specified using [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html),
> CMake will read this property from all target dependencies to
> determine the build properties of the consumer.

Comment: This is the first time I ever read an understandable explanation of the ```PUBLIC``` etc. properties! Thanks :D

Comment: Removing the ambiguity: when you use `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE` with  `target_include_directories`, the property `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`  is filled with the include directories required to compile against the headers for the target.

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243169/cmake-target-include-directories-meaning-of-scope_) if you want know more about the meaning of the keywords `PRIVATE`, `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` using `target_include_directories`

Answer (score 8):

As @Angew said, the very difference is :

1. `include_directories()` is accessible for all the files in the source-tree
2. `target_include_directories()` is-only accessible for a specific target when compile.