# Cmake cannot find header from library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have following structure in my project.

```
project-
  include-
  src-
     ab.cpp
     ab.h
  tests
     CMakeLists.txt
  CMakeLists.txt
```

I create library in `project/CMakeLists.txt` directory using `add_library`. In tests directory CMake, I use `target_link_libraries`. Now my test.cpp it does not find ab.h I have to use `target_include_directories` with `project/src` path. Does the `target_link_libraries` only finds header from `include` directory or what I am missing here?

Comment: `target_link_libraries` only effects linker settings, it has nothing to do with adding extra include locations

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/40244458/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40244458/487892)

Comment: Rather than knowing only the structure of your project, it would be necessary to see your CMakeLists.txt files to give sound advise.

Answer (score 0):

The actions necessary for linking are similar to regular flow of a C++ project.

For a project with this structure:

```
src
  A.cpp
  A.h
  B.cpp
  B.h
```

When code in `B.cpp` wants to use a function defined in `A.h` it needs to declare it  with `#include<A.h>` statement, this way the code of `A.h` is copied by the preprocessor so the translation unit of `B.cpp` is aware of it's existence.

In the link stage all object files are linked - the "promise" you made by declaring all `A.h` declarations are fulfilled by `A.o`.

Similarly, when `test.cpp` uses a function from a library - you first need to declare it, this is why you should use `target_include_directories` and include `ab.h` in `test.cpp`.

Then, for the linking stage you should let the linker know where the implementation of those functions declared in `ab.h` are found (your static/dynamic library file), for this you use `target_link_libraries`.