# Using CMake with templates

Tags: c++, templates, cmake

I've a small [git project](https://github.com/lukkio88/CPP-AlgAndDS/tree/master/BasicAlgorithmsAndDataStructures) for basic algorithms and data structure, and specifically I'm planning to change [this bit](https://github.com/lukkio88/CPP-AlgAndDS/tree/master/BasicAlgorithmsAndDataStructures/ElementaryDataStructures) with templates, at the moment everything is with integers. The `CMakeList.txt` is this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)
project(ElementaryDataStructures)

set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 )

include_directories(./)

set( HEADER_FILES list.h bstree.h rbtree.h)
set( SRC_FILES list.cpp bstree.cpp rbtree.cpp)

if(WIN32)
    set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS YES CACHE BOOL "Export all symbols")
endif()

add_library(elementary-data-structures SHARED ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
set_target_properties(elementary-data-structures PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
#set_target_properties(elemetary-data-structures PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

While the main CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)
project(CPP_Algorithms_and_Data_Structures)

set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 )

add_subdirectory(./ElementaryAlgorithms)
add_subdirectory(./ElementaryDataStructures)
add_subdirectory(./AdvancedDataStructures)
add_subdirectory(./GraphAlgorithms)

set(INCLUDE_FOLDERS 
    ./ElementaryAlgorithms 
    ./ElementaryDataStructures 
    ./AdvancedDataStructures 
    ./GraphAlgorithms)

include_directories(${INCLUDE_FOLDERS})

set(SRC_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(alg-and-ds ${SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(alg-and-ds 
    elementary-algorithms
    elementary-data-structures
    advanced-data-structures)
```

So basically I'd like to replace, for example, the definition of `List` in `list.h` with a template class and instead of having `list.cpp` I'd like to have a `list.tpp` for the implementation. How should my CMakeLists.txts be changed to support template?

Is it just including folders? or is there something subtle I should keep in mind?

**Update**

I did change one of my `CMakeLists.txt` as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)
project(ElementaryDataStructures)

set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 )

if(WIN32)
    set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS YES CACHE BOOL "Export all symbols")
endif()

add_library(elementary-data-structures SHARED "")
target_include_directories(elementary-data-structures PUBLIC ./)
target_sources(elementary-data-structures PUBLIC 
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/list.h"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/list.tcc")
set_target_properties(elementary-data-structures PROPERTIES     RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.16299.0 to target Windows 10.0.17134.
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: elementary-data                    -structures
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Lukkio/Project/CPP-AlgAndDS/build
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please consider using `target_include_directories` instead of the global `include_directories`.

Answer (score 1):

> How should my CMakeLists.txts be changed to support template?
>
> Is it just including folders? or is there something subtle I should keep in mind?

By going to templates you are also moving to a header-only library. Once you have replaced all the implementations, you will be left without .cpp files.

You don't need to do anything special. However, googling for "CMake Header-only library", you see the recommendation to mark your lib as "INTERFACE". [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39889958/461597), [2](http://mariobadr.com/creating-a-header-only-library-with-cmake.html)

- `target_sources` can be used to tell CMake the input files. Alternatively, you can implicitly export them through `target_include_directories`. However, that way they would not get installed, if you create a package (debian, etc) out of the library.

#### Recommendation

- Get rid of the directory-scoped `include_directories` by replacing it with `target_include_directories(elementary-data-structures PUBLIC .)`. `include_directories` is old-style CMake and should be avoided.

Comment: Not my best answer. Anyway, I think you are more or less fine by moving to an INTERFACE lib.

Comment: Can you please post the full cmakelists.txt? Including your suggestions, just for future references.

Comment: Deleted my answer. Probably more informed answers can be had

Comment: Also, despite I'm going through this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243169/cmake-target-include-directories-meaning-of-scope, I still don't get the meaning of `INTERFACE, PUBLIC, PRIVATE`.