# In CMake, when is target_link_libraries with INTERFACE useful?

Tags: cmake

In CMake, when is `target_link_libraries` with INTERFACE useful?

Reading documentation, question [CMake target_link_libraries Interface Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037954/cmake-target_link_libraries-interface-dependencies)  plus doing some test myself I came to the conclusion, when you do:

`target_link_library(foo INTERFACE bar)`

INTERFACE means in this example that whoever links 'foo': does have access to (so links) 'bar', but 'foo' itself does not use 'bar' in any way.

So library 'foo' can't use 'bar': it doesn't link it neither has it access to any of bar's include files (it can also not call inline functions at bar for example). So basically 'foo' has no access to 'bar' at all.

At question [CMake target_link_libraries Interface Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037954/cmake-target_link_libraries-interface-dependencies) (the answer by András Aszódi) it states '...One example of this is an interface library which simply forwards calls along to another library..."
But even this cannot be done, how can 'foo' forward anything to 'bar' when it doesn't have any access to it?

So why would you need that? Why would library `foo` say "I don not use library 'bar' myself at all, but whoever links me, must also link 'bar'".

Comment: "But even this cannot be done, how can 'foo' forward anything to 'bar' when it doesn't have any access to it?" - The phrase you cite - "One example of this is an interface library which simply forwards calls along to another library" - is not about forwarding to `bar`, it is about forwarding to **other library** which links with `foo` (e.g. by `target_link_libraries(mylib PRIVATE foo)`. Note also that given phrase is about the library defined as `add_library(foo INTERFACE)`. Such library has no sources to compile, so PRIVATE linkage for it is no-op, and PUBLIC linkage is same as INTERFACE.

Comment: I have marked your question post as a duplicate of the [referenced one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037954/cmake-target_link_libraries-interface-dependencies), as the other question post answers the question you put at the beginning - "In CMake, when is target_link_libraries with INTERFACE useful?".

Comment: The referenced issue indeed describes what target_link_library with PUBLIC/PRIVATE/INTERFACE does (how it works), but does not answer my question asked here: when is it ever useful to use target_link_library with INTERFACE.

Comment: "When A links B as INTERFACE, it is saying that A does not use B in its implementation, but B is used in A's public API. " - Isn't this an example where INTERFACE is useful?

Comment: This is how I expected it to work, but it does not. A also has no access to the include files of B when linking B as INTERFACE. So A also has no access to B's API so how can B be used in A's public API in that case.

Comment: "This is how I expected it to work, but it does not"  - What do you mean by "expected to work" and "doesn't work" when talk about **abstract example**? "So A also has no access to B's API so how can B be used in A's public API in that case." - Public API of the library A is something that the library **wants** to be accessible by its **users**. It is perfectly to correct for implementation (source files) of A to not use a header which is provided as the library's interface.